# Where can I find (Wheel alignment softwares) to download and use?

Tags: wheels, alignment, wheel-balance

I've been searching the web for a long time to find any wheel alignment softwares but I couldn't find any ! please inform me if you know where to download or buy one. Thank you

Comment: Why software? A straight-edge and a steel ruler will do...

Comment: my brother has a machine for wheel alignment and the software he uses is outdated, meaning a lot of new cars do not exist in the vehicles list. The software came pre installed with the machine and we couldn't reach the manufacturer as it is located in china.

Comment: This type of software is very specific to the manufacturer, usually the only source for updates is the manufacturer themselves. Maybe you can find a user group which shares updates if you hunt for it. In any case your question cannot possibly be answered without knowing the manufacturer and model of the alignment machine you're asking about.

Comment: Software???? plenty of tutorials on youtube

Comment: I'm guessing what you mean is an update to the list of vehicle geometry settings?

Comment: Hello, sorry for taking this long to reply. Yes I want an update to the list of vehicle geometry settings, the model of the alignment machine is: Vameg 3D Wheel Alignment